# laravel eloquent multiple tables where criteria

Tags: php, laravel

I have spent two days trying to solve this issue but no luck.
I have 3 tables, categories, items and related items, every item is under one category and category can have many items, this part working fine, now the issue is in related item, I have in the table realteditems 3 fields, id(just autoincrement), ritemf_id,riteml_id those refers to item_id in items table.
What I want to do is to display item with its details and related items to this item, means if item1 have many realted items,such item2,item3,item4  .. so need to display like this

**item_title:** item1

**related item:**

item2

item3

item4

**controller**

```
   $items = Item::orderBy('category_id', 'asc')->with('category')->get()->groupBy('category_id');

   $categories = Category::orderBy('category_id', 'asc')->get();

   return view('home',['items' => $items,'ritems' => $ritems,'categories' => $categories]);
```

**items modal**

```
 public function category() 
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
   }
 public function relateditems() 
 {
 return $this->belongsTo('App\Relateditem', 'ritemf_id');       
  }
```

**relateditems modal:**

```
 class Relateditem extends Model
  {
    protected $table="relateditems";
   protected $fillable=['ritemf_id','riteml_id'];
   protected $primaryKey='id';
   public $timestamps=false;
 public function items() 
 {  
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'item_id');
 }
 }
```

**showing items with its category in blade(working fine)**

```
 @if (!empty($categoryItems->first()->category))        
 {{ $categoryItems->first()->category->category_name }} @else {{$category_id}} @endif

   @foreach($categoryItems as $item)
 {{$item->item_title}}
  ${{$item->item_price}}
 @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference between `ritemf_id` and `riteml_id`. what's there use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix both relations in `Item` Model and `RelatedItem` model. relateditems should be `hasMany` because an item can have many related item.
You also need to define `belongsTo` relation in RelatedItem to Item using `riteml_id` key

**Item modal**

```
public function category() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
}

public function relateditems() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Relateditem', 'ritemf_id');       
}
```

**Relateditem modal:**

```
class Relateditem extends Model
 {
    protected $table="relateditems";
    protected $fillable=['ritemf_id','riteml_id'];
    protected $primaryKey='id';
    public $timestamps=false;

    public function item() //i have change it to item instead items, because belongsTo always return single record
    {  
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'riteml_id');
    }
 }
```

**Fetch Data**

```
$items = Item::orderBy('category_id', 'asc')->with('category','relateditems', 'relateditems.item')->get()->groupBy('category_id');

foreach($items as $categoryId => $groupItems){
   echo $groupItems->first()->category;
   foreach($groupItems as $item) {
       echo $item->item_tile;
       ...
       foreach($item->relateditems as $relatedItem){
           if ($relatedItem->item){
              echo $relatedItem->item->item_tile; //this will show you related item title
           }
       }
    }
}
```

**For Single Item**

```
   $item = Item::with('category','relateditems', 'relateditems.item')->find(1);

   foreach($item->relateditems as $relatedItem){
       if ($relatedItem->item){
          echo $relatedItem->item->item_tile; //this will show you related item title
       }
   }
```

Comment: in the fetch data section what do you mean by 'relateditems.item'?

Comment: relatedItems table has only the `riteml_id` referencing item table and from this you will get the related items list. relateditems will only give you the related items ids not the referenced `Item`

Comment: relateditems have two refrennces ritemf_id  and riteml_id

Comment: yes, what do you reference them with ? check `Relateditem` model i have added a relation `return $this->belongsTo('App\Item', 'riteml_id');`

Comment: Ok the problem is I have items in the table items, in the same time maybe some of these items have related item, not all items, so I thought I can make another table to show the related items, and this is why this tables have tow fields because maybe item1 have related 2,3,4, do you have any other idea to design the related table?

Comment: this is fine, you can go with this design. can you tell me what you store in `ritemf_id` and `riteml_id` ? because the answer i have given is based on assumption after looking your code

Comment: the related items are the same items, this is for catering food,  so if one choose chicken want to tell him that people also choose with Chicken salads, soup, where salads and chicken and soup are items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174110/discussion-between-rkj-and-ahktm).

Answer (score 1):

`relateditems()`definition looks incorrect to me in `Item` model, Item may have more than one related items then this should be `hasMany/beongsToMany` association.

Assume its `hasMany`  then update your item model as

```
public function relateditems()  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Relateditem', 'ritemf_id');       
}
```

And eager load your related items for each item

```
$items = Item::orderBy('category_id', 'asc')
             ->with(['category', 'relateditems'])
             ->get()
             ->groupBy('category_id');
```

I assume the [`groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-groupby) method is used from collection class to group retrieved data not on database side

Comment: I tried to use your solution but its not working for me, so if I used the same way as Im doing for showing items and categories, I used this $ritems = Relateditem::orderBy('ritemf_id', 'asc')->with('items')->get()->groupBy('ritemf_id'); after modifing the modal but it only shows the data from related item, you know there is a loop for every item this loop contains the related item